# MapKit Annotations not showing up on map

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm having trouble getting the MKAnnotationViews show up on the map in MapKit. I'm using iOS 7, and have now searched the forums and the web for many hours, trying different samples and setups.

Below I have the most basic setup possible (I think) to make it work. The app contains a single ViewController with a toolbar with a button on top, and the rest is the MapView. The button triggers the method zoomToUser:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender. Right-clicking and checking my outlets and delegates seem to be correct. I have some NSLog-statements being triggered to output some debug info.

First the VC:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Data.h"

@interface ViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
- (IBAction)zoomToUser:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    Data *ann = [[Data alloc] init];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        [self zoomToUser:nil];
    }

-(IBAction)zoomToUser:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 2000, 2000);
    NSLog(@"region: %f x %f",self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES ];
    NSArray *arr = self.mapView.annotations;
    for(int i = 0, max = arr.count; i < max; i++)
    {
        id<MKAnnotation> annotation = arr[i];
        NSLog(@"%d of %d: %@ (%@)",i+1,max,annotation.title, [annotation class]);
    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    NSString *reuseId = @"Test";
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else if( [annotation isKindOfClass:[Data class]])
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annov = [mapView    dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
        if(!annov)
        {
            annov = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        }
        else
        {
            annov.annotation = annotation;
        }
        annov.canShowCallout = YES;
        NSLog(@"Title: %@",annotation.title);
        return annov;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
@end
```

And the `Data` class:

```
#import "Data.h"

@implementation Data

-(NSString *)title
{
    return @"The title";
}

-(NSString *)subtitle
{
    return @"A subtitle";
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = 60.123456;
    coordinate.longitude = 10.123456;
    return coordinate;
}

@end
```

The Data.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Data : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@end
```

And the ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

As you can see the `viewForAnnotation`-method prints the annotations title in console when it's requested, and each time the map pans the area, it prints.

Pressing the BarButton and triggering the `zoomToUser:`-method logs to console that the map indeed has two annotations, the `MKUserLocation` and the one I added.

How come my MapView tells me it has the annotation, it asks for the view, it gets the view, but it does not show it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `viewForAnnotation`, the code is creating and returning an `MKAnnotationView` for annotations of type `Data`.

The `MKAnnotationView` class, by default, creates an empty view.
That is, its `image` property is `nil` and the view basically contains no content.
So, as-is, the annotation views are being created and added but they are invisible.

You can either:

- Set the `image` property on the `MKAnnotationView`:

  ```
  annov.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"something"];
  ```
- Or, simpler, create an `MKPinAnnotationView` instead which is a convenient subclass of `MKAnnotationView` that displays a pin image for you:

  ```
  MKPinAnnotationView *annov = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeue...
  if(!annov)
  {
      annov = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                          reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
      annov.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;  //or Green or Purple
  }
  else
  ...
  ```

**Unrelated**:
You've created a custom annotation class `Data` which is fine but if all you need are the three properties `title`, `subtitle`, and `coordinate`, then you can just use the pre-defined `MKPointAnnotation` class which lets you set all the properties per-instance:

```
MKPointAnnotation *ann = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
ann.title = @"The title";
ann.subtitle = @"A subtitle";
ann.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake (60.123456, 10.123456);
[self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really can't believe I missed that... I guess i haven't looked too closely at the parts of code where the annotation views are customized.

Regarding the annotations class: I will be collecting the data for the pins from core data, but I figured it would be too much code to paste, but I wanted to show some of the related parts of the annotation class. It is actually implemented using categories on top of the already categorized subclass of NSManagedObject. Wish I could upvote, but I haven't got the reputation. Thanks again!